# Function to create key-value pairs from two object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm parsing a 2 column CSV file with d3.csv. Is there an existing JS, jQuery, or D3 function to turn the result into key-value pairs?

Example CSV input:

```
Option      Value
first_name  Don
last_name   Smith
```

Example d3.csv output from Chrome console:

```
{ option: "first_name", value: "Don" },
{ option: "last_name", value: "Smith" }
```

Below is the output I would like (I want to use the option as a key, and the value as a ... value):

```
[{ first_name: "don" }, { last_name: "Smith" }]
```

If there is no existing function I was going to code something that loops through the object, and uses "option" as the new key, and "value" as it's value. I assumed something like this has already been written.

Comment: `...loops through the object` - which object, how should this object look like? Note that `example output` in your question is not an object - it's two separate ones. And no JS object is able to have two identical keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
function makeArrayWithOptionAsKey(oldDataArray) {
    var newDataArray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<oldDataArray.length; i++) {
        var option = oldDataArray[i]['option'];
        var value = oldDataArray[i]['value'];
        newDataArray.push({ option: value });
    }
    return newDataArray;
}
```

If this is what you're looking for you could also use JQuery's map:

```
var arrayWithObjectAsKey = $.map(myObjList, function (el, i) {
    var newElement = {};
    newElement[el['option']] = el['value'];
    return newElement;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm getting an error about the opening bracket in `element['option']`. Any ideas? Trying to debug now

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` - recreating in jsfiddle right now

Comment: i'm assuming you're going with the Jquery solution. Do you have proper quotation marks around 'option' and 'value'?

Comment: yea it's pretty much just copy-pasted from your example with a new value for oldArray

Comment: @DonnyP it seems that in javascript object literal syntax, there are things you can't do to make keys. Try my most recent code.